# Format UIAlert View

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have a UIAlert view popping up when a button is pressed. I want to have separate lines of text, certain text in each line. When I currently run the app, it shows it in the paragraph. This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)popupalert:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Lesson Timing" message:
                      @"Lesson 1: 7:40-8:20, Lesson 2: 8:22-9:02, Breakfast Break: 9:02-9:15, Lesson 3: 9:15-9:55, Lesson 4: 9:57-10:37, Lesson 5: 10:39 - 11:19, Second Break: 11:19-11:29, Lesson 6: 11:29-12:09, Lesson 7: 12:11-12:51, Lesson 8: 12:53-1:33, Lunch Break: 1:33-1:58, Private Study: 1:58-2:38, Lesson 9: 2:40-3:15" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

}
```

I want each lesson to be on a different line.

Comment: Just use standard line break `\n` where you want a line to move onto the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to put the text on separate lines, you can do so by formatting the string with line break (`\n`) characters, e.g.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Lesson Timing" 
                                               message:@"Lesson 1: 7:40-8:20, \nLesson 2: 8:22-9:02, \nBreakfast Break: 9:02-9:15, \nLesson 3: 9:15-9:55, \nLesson 4: 9:57-10:37, \nLesson 5: 10:39 - 11:19, \nSecond Break: 11:19-11:29, Lesson 6: 11:29-12:09, Lesson 7: 12:11-12:51, Lesson 8: 12:53-1:33, Lunch Break: 1:33-1:58, \nPrivate Study: 1:58-2:38, \nLesson 9: 2:40-3:15" 
                                              delegate:nil 
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" 
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```